# I have a problem with sysklogd on gentoo linux

Tags: linux, gentoo

> first picture[image]
> second picture[image]

when I start the system it gives me an error with the sysklogd logs in the first image the error is found and in the second the output of / var / logs

(I use profile: default)

Comment: What does `mount` indicate about the filesystems, and are you getting any messages about mounting issues in `dmesg`? There may be an issue with the filesystem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Is `/var` mounted on a disk partition, or part of the `/` file system?  If it's a partition, check the options in `/etc/fstab`